# Employer is trying to fire me after I have resigned

Tags: professionalism, management, human-resources, united-kingdom

Firstly, I would really appreciate any help that anyone can give me.

I have resigned from the company that I work with and have given my notice. I will soon leave said company, however, my employer is trying to fire me whilst I am in the process of leaving.

I have worked for the company for over a year - and I recalled the managers doing something extremely similar to one of my co-workers. Essentially, they fired her giving her 3 strikes which they had brought them all on her at once. From what she had told me, the mistakes she had made were innocent, i.e. given customer wrong tender/not scanned an item etc. Lots of the coworkers had agreed that they were harsh but, since they were mistakes and they had the jurisdiction, nonetheless they fired her.

Now this links to my situation since my managers have treated me very badly. And I have observed them doing the same thing now to me as they did to her. Now the situations pertaining to myself were that I had also given the customer the wrong tender.

I was originally on good terms with my manager, but it is clear that he is trying to fire me, as they are doing exactly what they had done to my colleague/friend.

In my situation, the number 2 manager alerted me that they intend to contact HR over a situation that had occurred 2 months ago. I have seizures and panic attacks that occur infrequently. I am an introverted person and I have high anxiety and so only a few people know about this - and I had not alerted these managers.

Now the other situation being that I had incorrectly returned an item - the number 2 disputes that I should not have done this. I argue that this could not be attributed to myself and that I would have followed the manager's advice and never claimed responsibility in doing so.

The third situation is that when I have a seizure/p.a I took an "unscheduled break". I do not want other staff/customers etc. to see me when I go through one of these episodes. And so I would either leave the store, or go into a closet so that I could not been in this situation.

Now the manager that had noticed that I was missing on the day of my seizure/p.a., told me that I shouldn't be leaving "unscheduled". Reluctantly I told her what had happened and she said just don't go again and also that she wouldn't tell the head manager about this. She assumed that I just take extra breaks. However on one day in the past, this manager took an unscheduled break. I noted the day that this had happened and myself and another colleague saw her do this. Additionally, there are cameras where the colleague was and so there should not be any doubt that she was in the wrong in this case. I do not know whether I should report this. However, since she reported me for this "unscheduled break" today that I took after I had given my notice - I am unsure what this would look like if I report her for this. The other manager (not the head one) told me that they would report this to HR despite this happening over a month ago.

Now my employer is trying to fire me via my other managers. As I have said I have already provided my resignation but the other managers that I work with on the remaining shifts that I am scheduled to work are extremely rude to me.

Additionally, I have evidence of a phone call that I made to the head manager of when I fell ill and he had said that she does not believe me verbatim. I provided him with a doctor's note and he just left it as it was.

The other managers today were forcing me to sign documents to acknowledge these "mistakes".  However, I declined and said that I would discuss this with the head manager. I was warned prior to this by other colleagues to not sign anything that I did not agree with and so did not. If I had signed this, they would contact HR immediately to take this further.  However, I declined to sign anything.

From when I provided my notice, my manager changed my staff review to the worst possible, as in from A to D where A is best. I was originally given a C by one of the other managers - to which the head manager reassigned me with a D.

I do not have the strength nor confidence to go back to this company to work my remaining shifts. I am strongly considering getting a doctor's note in hopes that I do not have to work these shifts as I am suffering severe anxiety from all of this. This is detrimental to my health and I feel sick and uneasy going to that workplace.

I have a few remaining shifts, although I am sure that the manager will fire me owing to these "mistakes/errors".

I know this was long to read but I would be so appreciative to anyone if they could help me.

I never want to go there back again if anyone can advise me what to do, I would be extremely grateful. I am strongly considering just not to turn up to the remaining shifts, although this would look very bad on my part. And although this company would never give me a good reference in future, I do not want to be fired, especially since I have previously resigned.

Should I go see a doctor? Should I email HR myself? Should I just not turn up to the remaining shifts?

If you are absent via sickness then you are typically told to call in, and I have evidence i.e. a recorded conversation of the head manager saying that he doesn't believe me.

Thank you.

-M

**Clarification: Following constructive responses from everyone who has posted in this thread I will not return to that hell. I will seek medical help with the issues that I am going through in aim to get myself excused from working the remaining period. Many thanks again to everyone who has responded/helped I sincerely appreciate the time and effort you have all made in helping me x**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78751/discussion-on-question-by-mihay10micox-employer-is-trying-to-fire-me-after-i-hav).

Comment: Too much information.  Why do you care if they fire you?  At least in the US, getting fired is usually a better deal (can go on unemployment, etc.) as opposed to just quitting.  And you wouldn't have the notice period.  Is it just the "shame factor?"

Comment: Being fired is a big red flag on the CV: what did you do so badly that they chose to kick you out?! Resigning is sellable: I chose to leave because I wanted to, maybe even they wanted me to stay. @mxyzplk

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If this is how they treat you when you resign, there's no point waiting out your notice period. You needn't worry about not getting a reference as their treatment (abuse) of you indicates you aren't going to get one. Fear not about a negative reference as that can be grounds for defamation.

As you are in the UK:

https://www.gov.uk/taking-sick-leave

This government information site indicates that an employee call in sick 7 days in a row before requiring a sick cert. Use this for your remaining shifts.

Comment: thank you so much for the continued help. I am sorry if I neglected to mention this, but for the remaining contracted shifts that I have to work they are over a 7 day period in which case I would require a sick cert I think?

Comment: @mihay10micox not sure I fully understand. Are you saying you have to work more than 7 shifts? I wouldn't worry about it to be honest. You've already stated they intend to fire you simply because you resigned, so it's largely irrelevant what you do. They are not showing any loyalty to you, so you don't need to show them any loyalty.

Comment: Sorry if I made this unclear. I have to work a couple more shifts spread over 12 days. My resignation would officially take into effect after the last shift at the end of the 12 day period. If I called in sick as you had said then that would only cover me for 7 days afaik, where I would need 12. Thank you for your help btw I genuinely appreciate it. If I may ask you - should I get a medical note to say that owing to my anxiety/panic attacks that I cannot work.

Comment: @mihay10micox Take the 7 days off work and if you feel like it talk to a doctor during the time off if you can afford to do so. It doesn't matter what happens at this point. From their treatment of you, you won't be getting a reference. There's no point in working in an environment that causes medical issues. Seriously, just do what is best for your health and not bother with them any more.  You have nothing to gain by staying there other than maybe some cash, but it's not worth the stress.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice - hopefully if one of my colleagues picks up one of the shifts that I have then the period between 2 shifts will be 7 days which will cover me from the link that you have provided. I really appreciate the help/guidance you have given me. If I could upvote your post I would :) Thanks again :)

Comment: @mihay10micox no worries, hope it works out for you.

Comment: I'll let you know what happens if you would like :) Thank you for the kind words and the advice :)

Comment: @user1666620 She will be getting a reference. And if that reference contains anything negative, then any employment lawyer will only be too happy to make them pay.

Answer (score 8):

Don't just leave. You have given your notice and should work until the end of your notice period. If you get fired you stop working when they tell you and you can then take a lawyer, or go to the citizens advice bureau, to get pay until the end of your notice period. If you just leave, you give up your rights, and it could have disadvantages for unemployment insurance. If you have medical issues, this is a good time to get a sicknote from your doctor and look after your health.

Obviously if you go to work and have problems, then you can walk straight to HR and discuss it with them. Not so much to get results, but to get away from your manager. And if your manager makes you feel bad, you can make HR feel bad.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For reference I am a college student. As for unemployment insurance I would not apply for that. I would rather seek another job or take a break from working. As for the sicknote, I definitely agree that I should seek help. I just want to leave they have treated me horribly. This is just a part time job not relevant to my major or career in future. I am really unsure of what to do. :'(

Comment: "As for unemployment insurance I would not apply for that." Don't admit that to HR. I do not know how things work in your jurisdiction, but in mine, HR would halt all this nonsense about firing you during your notice period if they thought you were going to apply for unemployment insurance if fired. That's because where I am located. Resigning doesn't get you unemployment insurance, but getting fired does. Plus getting unemployement insurance raises the premiums the company has to pay. So if you do qualify for it (may be you don't), but do not let them off the hook by telling them you won't.

Comment: I'm not familiar with labor laws in other countries. In my country "getting fired" is better. If you're fired, you get compensation (mandated by law, and can be as much as a whole year of salary under certain circumstances). If you quit, you walk away with just the worked days and the remaining vaction days you didn't take. (sometimes if you're in good terms with management, you can "ask to get you fired" and get that compensation. This is especially true when the company is preparing layoffs). Why does this person not want to get fired? Is it a stain in your curriculum?