# Process of taking a leave of absence due to severe anxiety

Tags: united-kingdom, leave-of-absence

I have made an appointment with my GP with the objective of them providing me with a leave of absence due to the severe anxiety I have.

Can I ask if anyone has had any experience with this - what should I tell my GP?

And additionally will a signed note from my doctor be sufficient in me being able to take a leave of absence.

I am from the UK.

Comment: Welcome to the workplace. Most of our UK users are asleep right now, but I'm sure you'll have some answers in the next day or so.  Please allow for some time before picking the best answer, as that will encourage more people to do so.  Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am meeting with my doctor post Tuesday. Thank you for the warm welcome x

Comment: Do you know that a leave of absence will be an effective treatment for your issue? Have you discussed this with your doctor before?

Comment: @SethR Not with the particular doctor that I will see. The one I have previously talked to is currently on holiday :/ This link here https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113779/employer-is-trying-to-fire-me-after-i-have-resigned/113784#113784     is my first post and stems for me meeting with my doctor. Thanks for you reply btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can self-certify absence from work through sickness for seven days in the UK. Beyond that:

> Can I ask if anyone has had any experience with this - what should I tell my GP?

The process is pretty much exactly the same as if you had to take time off for a physical illness.

Tell your GP the exact symptoms you've been having, and that because of these symptoms, you don't feel that you're able to work. Expect to answer questions around what if anything triggers your anxiety, and anything that you're doing to try to mitigate it at the moment. After their assessment they'll likely discuss options with you to try to treat or manage the condition (whether that's through medication, counselling or some other means), and they'll almost certainly want to schedule a follow up appointment.

Assuming they agree with your assessment that you're not fit to work at the moment, they'll give you a form that says you're unable to work until a certain date - you'll need to hand that form to your employer. Your GP may schedule a follow up appointment before the date you're set to go back to work to check that you're ok, and give you the option to extend your time off if you need it.

And as a side note, in most cases while you're sick, you're entitled to [statutory sick pay](https://www.gov.uk/statutory-sick-pay) - this is identical for any reason you're off sick, whether that's physical or mental health issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for this post, this is extremely useful and I appreciate the time you took in construing this to me. If I may please also ask you - by law am I able to self-certify a 7 day period of work i.e. Friday 15th - Friday 22nd (if I am working on both of these Fridays for example). I will discuss this with my GP hopefully my health improves. Thanks again x

Comment: @mihay10micox you're very welcome. Afraid I'm not sure of the specifics of the 7 day certification - I think it's be best to clarify this with your GP to be sure. All the best in your recovery.

Comment: I understand. Thank you again for your help and your kind words :)